# USB device not seen by Ubuntu

Tags: usb

I have just discovered that known working (tested on Win10 PC) USB thumbdrive and external drive are not recognized.
I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and kernel 4.15.0-24-generic.

Here is what I've tried so far based on Googling.

1. lsusb without USB plugged in and then again with USB plugged in. No change.
2. usb-devices gives the following output.

   ```
   T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 2
   D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
   P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=04.15
   S:  Manufacturer=Linux 4.15.0-24-generic ehci_hcd
   S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller
   S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:1a.0
   C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
   I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

   T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 6
   D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
   P:  Vendor=8087 ProdID=0024 Rev=00.00
   C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
   I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

   T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=04 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
   D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
   P:  Vendor=1bcf ProdID=288f Rev=1b.03
   S:  Manufacturer=CN01RH71724871CFD3ZMA00
   S:  Product=Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_1.3M
   C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
   I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
   I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo

   T:  Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 2
   D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
   P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=04.15
   S:  Manufacturer=Linux 4.15.0-24-generic ehci_hcd
   S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller
   S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:1d.0
   C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
   I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

   T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 8
   D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
   P:  Vendor=8087 ProdID=0024 Rev=00.00
   C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
   I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

   T:  Bus=02 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=04 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=12  MxCh= 0  
   D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
   P:  Vendor=8086 ProdID=0189 Rev=69.19
   C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
   I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
   I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb

   T:  Bus=03 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 2
   D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
   P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=04.15
   S:  Manufacturer=Linux 4.15.0-24-generic xhci-hcd
   S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
   S:  SerialNumber=0000:03:00.0
   C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
   I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

   T:  Bus=04 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=5000 MxCh= 2
   D:  Ver= 3.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=03 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
   P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0003 Rev=04.15
   S:  Manufacturer=Linux 4.15.0-24-generic xhci-hcd
   S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
   S:  SerialNumber=0000:03:00.0
   C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
   I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
   ```
3. sudo lsblk gives the following output.

   ```
   NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
   loop1    7:1    0  76.2M  1 loop /snap/drakon/1
   loop11   7:11   0 141.5M  1 loop /snap/chromium/367
   loop8    7:8    0  57.1M  1 loop /snap/notepad-plus-plus/77
   loop6    7:6    0  57.1M  1 loop /snap/notepad-plus-plus/70
   loop4    7:4    0  57.1M  1 loop /snap/notepad-plus-plus/74
   loop2    7:2    0  86.9M  1 loop /snap/core/4917
   loop0    7:0    0 139.8M  1 loop /snap/chromium/353
   loop9    7:9    0  86.6M  1 loop /snap/core/4650
   loop10   7:10   0 139.4M  1 loop /snap/chromium/343
   sda      8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk 
   ├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
   ├─sda5   8:5    0   3.3G  0 part [SWAP]
   └─sda1   8:1    0 115.9G  0 part /
   loop7    7:7    0  86.9M  1 loop /snap/core/4830
   loop5    7:5    0   198M  1 loop /snap/vlc/365
   ```
4. sudo dmesg -c to clear then sudo dmesg gives no output.
5. gparted and Disks only shows the internal HDD

EDIT (to add additional information)
6. LiveUSB of Ubuntu 18.04 boots successfully from only one (of two) USB ports and successfully reads an external USB drive from the other port, so hardware doesn't seem to be the problem.

What should I try next?

Comment: When you said Windows 10 PC, that was on another computer, right?  Have you tried booting your computer to a LiveCD or into another environment to eliminate software problems?

Comment: Correct, Win10 was on another computer. I just made a LiveUSB of Ubuntu 18.04. It boots only from one of my two USB ports and an external USB (tested earlier) shows up and can be read from the other USB port.

Comment: @Terrance I have edited the question to reflect my previous comment.

Comment: Hi, I seem to experiment the same problem as you. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found that a high speed (10) microSD card was read only if in usb2 slot, but in a usb3 slot it was ok. It may have to do with communication timing errors. Try a faster usb slot.